# What is the best data type, or preferred method for implementing multiple stacks in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, stack

In class the other day, our teacher mentioned creating multiple stacks within one data structure such as an array. Although we're not going to go further into it in this specific class, I'm curious and trying to write my own program with multiple stacks and i can't figure out the best way, or really any way to go about it.

```
const int SIZE = 100;
template <class S>
class Plates{
public: //assume functions are defined
    bool full();
    bool empty();
    S top();
    void push();//once full true create new stack
    void pop();
private:
S plates[SIZE];
int index;
};
```

I'm trying to make a program that is simple and makes sense to me, so I'm using plates as an example and I want to try to create a new int stack - Stackplate etc. every time that the plates are stacked 10 high.

I've already read into multiple forums in which they suggest using an array, but the farthest I've seen implementation go is 3 arrays, but most have two with one starting at arr[0] and the other at arr[SIZE-1] and then moving one in the positive direction and the other in the negative direction so that eventually they would meet in the middle.

I don't know if it's possible to do this within a one dimensional array, or if a linked list would maybe be better, or really anything. Any suggestions or preferred methods would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-two-stacks-in-an-array/

Comment: It can be done with any backing storage data structure, but you should start with a static array (`std::array`) or dynamic array (`std::vector`). It is also the easiest way. Please clarify the question if you've encountered a concrete problem in your implementation, otherwise there isn't really much to talk about.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for what I want to do is to create a vector of stacks or an array of stacks..

Solution:

```
int main(){
   vector<stack<int>> etc...
```